# How to consume from topic MassTransit

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm trying to consume from a topic using Masstransit, but I can't understand how to call the consume-method?

Here is my configuration:

```
    services.AddMassTransit(serviceCollectionConfigurator =>
    {
        serviceCollectionConfigurator.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(busFactoryConfigurator =>
        {
            var host = busFactoryConfigurator.Host(new Uri(serviceBusConfig.HostName), hostConfigurator =>
            hostConfigurator.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(
                serviceBusConfig.SharedAccessKey,
                serviceBusConfig.Key));

                //busFactoryConfigurator.Message<IInterface>(topology => topology.SetEntityName(sevicesBusConfig.TopicName));

                // Subscribe to topic with a subscription
                busFactoryConfigurator.SubscriptionEndpoint(serviceBusConfig.Subscription, serviceBusConfig.TopicName, e =>
            {
                e.ConfigureConsumer<ConsumeMessageService>(provider);
            });
        }));
    });
```

Here is my ConsumerMessageService

```
public class ConsumeMessageService : IConsumeMessageService, IConsumer<MessageA>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MessageA> context)
    {
        return context.RespondAsync(new ResponseA { Value = context.Message.ToString() });
    }
}

public class ResponseA
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

How can I access the Consume-method from another service? Must I create a Context and then send it as a parameter?

EDIT:
I currently have 2messages in Azure Service Bus. How can I get the messages and return them to the controller? In some how I must retrieve the messages from the ConsumerService and return It to the controller. How can I do that? Can you please show me an example of this? I can't get my head around this and understand how I do this..

Comment: MassTransit calls your consumer, that's the whole point. You don't start the bus and it won't work. Please read the docs about hosting MT in ASP.NET Core app https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev: So how can I capture the messages from my domain-layer?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev: I must in some way be able to capture a message from my domain layer?

Comment: I honestly don't know what you mean. I think you might benefit from watching podcasts by Chris to get you started. Check it out https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/live-coding.html

Comment: Good suggestion, and yes, MassTransit invokes and calls your consumer similar to how an ASP.NET controller action method is called.

Comment: Watch the videos, seriously. That is entirely covered, including request/response.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson: I have started to watch the first video, and request/response isn't really the thing I'm after. Basically, I have a external application (Application A) that publish events to a topic in Azure Service Bus. Now I have another Application (Application B), that should listen to this topic for new events via an subscription to that topic. Which video should I look into that covers this? Thanks!

Comment: You're really asking basic stuff, I'd consider looking at some examples or maybe visiting the discord channel.